# How do I access my redux state in a component static navigationOptions?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

to access redux state after

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props) // works fine
}
```

but...

I want to get a value from my props.reduxState and assign it to title in

```
static navigationOptions = (props) => {
    title : props.reduxState.myValue
} // is UNDEFINED
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is set value of you props in componentDidMount and get your state from navigation.state.params

```
  componentDidMount() {
     this.props.navigation.setParams({
      myValue :this.props.myValue
     });
    }

  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const params = navigation.state.params || {}
    return {title: params.myValue}
  }
```

Comment: I should of updated this.  This is exactly what I ended up doing.  Worth pointing out, this did cause my screen to render a second time (very quickly) on the setParams call I believe.  Also, don't forget the 'return' which made me debug for an extra hour.